# SELECT ,DISTINCT and COUNT data from distincted value SQL

Tags: mysql

How to distinct value,and count data from distincted values base on this data

```
   NAME |                  NAME | TOTAL
    A   |                   A   |   4
    A   |                   B   |   2
    A   |     INTO THIS
    A   |
    B   |
    B   |
```

i already tried this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) ,COUNT(DISTINCT(NAME)) FROM tbl_a
```

but it shows only,even i used group by,and order by...

```
NAME |  TOTAL
 A   |    4
```

Comment: You forgot to give us the query you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select NAME, COUNT(NAME)  
from tbl_a
group by NAME;
```

Comment: this works ! thanks !

Comment: i had to wait 9 more minutes to mark the answer

Comment: Ok, cool, whenever you can. Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name_column) AS some_alias FROM table_name`

Comment: i tried this one,but only distinct the NAME column,not showing total of distincted values,but thanks